# Usage of generics with windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, generics, coding-style

I wish to create custom control with Items property.

Is it safe to return class `ItemColection` that implements `IList<Item>`, because i didn't saw this in any prebuilt controls?

What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem to create a property of type inherited from ILIst for a control. But if you are building a control it's better to make your property editable with PropertyGrid in design time. To make it editable you should create your own collection of items inherited from *CollectionBase* and create a property of that type.

Check out this article: [Creating a Custom Collection for Use in a PropertyGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/propertygridcollection.aspx)

And after that don't forget to make your Items property editable in design time by setting appropriate attributes:

```csh
[Browsable(true), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public YourItemsCollection Items
{
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use pretty much anything. A Form is (just) a class.

That you don't see examples is mostly due to the fact that WinForms is a .NET 1.0 technology. Very few additions or changes since then.

And unless you need specific functionality, just keep it simple:

```
public IList<ItemType> ItemsCollection  { get ...   set ... }
```

Comment: +1 - in general though you don't need a setter on a collection property.

Comment: Right, or make it private. I left it a little schematic, don't want to read things into the question.